# Comma use before "as"?

Tags: commas

I'm writing an essay and I was wondering if I would put a comma here before *as*:

> Reputation is based on integrity and wisdom *as* your ability to demonstrate probity would gain you favor among many people.

Comment: I would.  (But I would probably split the sentence in two.)

Comment: It certainly helps. After all, punctuation is not about grammar but improved readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As* adds nothing here.  Get rid of it and use two separate sentences:

*Reputation is based on integrity and wisdom.  Your ability to demonstrate probity would gain you favor among many people.*

Comment: Yes, it's essentially a restatement, a paraphrase / appositive, rather than an explanation of the first statement. 'As' is incorrect.